# Bug in AppBarLayout: wrong title behavior when initially collapsed

Tags: title, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I use typical AppBarLayout-CollapsingToolbarLayout-Toolbar bundle, and it works ok. But when I add `app:expanded="false"` or `appBarLayout.setExpanded(false)` before `collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle()`, I have behavior shown in video below.
https://youtu.be/OgSJomzYmek

Here is layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:expanded="false"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/action_bar_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/img_nature"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

It must be bug in support library.

Is there solution to correctly collapse toolbar, or any workaround?

---

**Update 1.**

Have found "solution". In short:

1. Override CollapsingToolbarLayout onLayout

   `onLayout(changed, ...) {
       if (changed) super.onLayout(true, ...);
   }`

Nothing more to override. Than use this custom CollapsingToolbarLayout  instead of from support library one.
Do not understand why, but this is necessary.

2. In Activity

   `appBarLayout.post(... here first call of appBarLayout.setCollapsed() ... )`

Do not use AppBarLayout until it completely measured and laid out.

**Update 2.**

Update 1 not works perfectly. Much better solution - works ok, at least for a while:
Another solution, seems works perfect, at least for a while...

```
public class Toolbar extends android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar {

    private Integer offset = null;

    public Toolbar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public Toolbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public Toolbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void offsetTopAndBottom(int offset) {
        super.offsetTopAndBottom(offset);
        if (this.offset == null)
            this.offset = offset;
    }

    @Override
    public int getTitleMarginTop() {
        return offset == null ? super.getTitleMarginTop() : -getTop() + offset + super.getTitleMarginTop();
    }

    @Override
    public int getTitleMarginBottom() {
        return offset == null ? super.getTitleMarginBottom() : getTop() - offset + super.getTitleMarginBottom();
    }

}
```

That's all.
When ABL's `setExpanded` is called, it follows to CTL's `onLayout`: `getDescendantRect` and then `mCollapsingTextHelper.setCollapsedBounds`.
At this moment `getDescendantRect` calculates base absolute position for title. And calculated position, I suppose, has error - it's shifted on (`CTL height` - `Window inset` - `Toolbar height`). The code above corrects this error.